# PHP include mysqli() class within main php class

Tags: php, mysqli

good day!

Im having the folowing problem with my php project. I tried to include mysqli() class within my main class in PHP. THIS IS THE FIRST PROJECT WHICH I BUILD USING OOP IN PHP.

i have the folowing code:

```
<?php
    class php{
    public function __construct($siteName,$sqlHost,$sqlUser,$sqlPass,$dbName){
        $this->info['SiteName']=$siteName;
    }
        //      vars
    public $info=array(
                    'SiteName'=>null,
                    'Author'=>'Costa V',
                    'Version'=>0,
                    'Build'=>0,
                    'LastUpdate'=>null);
    private $sql=new mysqli($sqlHost,$sqlUser,$sqlPass,$dbName);
        //      functions
    }
?>
```

i also have a main.php document where i initiate this class with:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$php=new php('Gerador de catalogo AVK','localhost','root','','avk_pdf_gen');
$pdf=new fpdf();
?>
```

where i get an error related the 'new' keyword in '$sql' variable.

Also i would like to ask you to rate my code and tip me with any useful advices related to OOP.

Comment: you can't have properties instantiated at compile-time with a definition that has to be performed in run-time. This is something you should move to your constructor instead. (ie. the entire private $sql=... should be replaced with a simple private $sql; and then in your __construct() function you do $this->sql = new mysqli

Comment: Did the answer I gave give you the information you needed? If so, please mark it as correct. Else feel free to follow up with more questions as comments to the answer, if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a good idea to initialise variables in the constructor.
Especially when the variables you try to initialise the `mysqli` object with does not exist anywhere else than inside the constructor function.
Try:

```
class php {
   private $sql;
   public function __construct($siteName,$sqlHost,$sqlUser,$sqlPass,$dbName){
      // The parameters that are passed into the constructor when you do 'new php(..)'
      // only exist within the constructor.
      $this->info['SiteName']=$siteName;
      $this->sql = new mysqli($sqlHost, $sqlUser, $sqlPass, $dbName);
  }
  // So if you are using the parameters passed into the constructor here 
  // (within the class declaration scope)
  // They are not yet existing.
}
```